# WARNING: version (0.2) should have exactly three components

Tags: r, package, release, devtools

When doing `devtools::release()`, this warning message came out.

I wrote version number `0.2` in my description file. However, what does it mean by **"should have exactly three components"**?

I'm not sure what exactly "components" indicates.

Here is the full output:

```
-- Running additional devtools checks for package -------------------------------
Checking version number has three components...
WARNING: version (0.2) should have exactly three components
Checking dependencies don't rely on dev versions... OK
Checking vignette titles are not placeholders... OK
Checking DESCRIPTION doesn't have Remotes field... OK
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a version number that has 3 integer components separated by `.`:

```
Version: 0.2.0
```

See [here](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/description.html) for more.

Comment: In the `MRAN`, some packages show `_` instead of `.`